# Laws of Mourning - Cutting Hair (w.r.t. Rav Ovadia z"l)

Tags: time, mourning-aveilus, hair, hacham-ovadia-yosef

I was interested to know what practice the sons of Rav Ovadia z"l had followed in regard to cutting their hair after the passing of their father?

I.e., for how many months did they leave their hair uncut?

Furthermore, in general, what is the accepted halacha? Are there any extra stringencies that some poskim suggest?

I am referring to the laws of mourning after a parent.

Comment: Why don't you try asking one? http://shut.moreshet.co.il/advancedSearchResult.asp?i=0&nop=20&WholeWord=0&rabonim=10468&x=7&y=6